# Reading properties in spring boot with half known key

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to read a property in spring boot where the property file has values like `"US.georgia.visa.2233 = 4400,
US.georgia.master.2322=0033,
US.NC.visa.4321=2344"`

now sometimes I will get have 3rd value or 4 value in the key(they are not redundant) how to read the key?? something like `"US.georgia.?.2233 or US.NC.visa.?"`

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but a workaround could be to have property list instead of properties : for example US.georgia.visa[0] = 4400, US.NC.visa[1]=2344 or even US.georgia.visa[0] =2233|4400 then split your string to retrieve yours values {2233, 4400} in the java code

Comment: What kind of data structure do you want to store these properties?